# Different background images for the same styled-component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components in my React Project, and I have one styled.div that I use for 2 different sections in my homepage.
The styled component looks like this:

```
    export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px green solid;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-image: url(${img});
    background-size:cover;
`
```

Is there any way of changing the background-image without duplicating the styled component? To archieve different backgrounds for each section of the homepage?

Comment: Wrap a component around your styled component, and pass a prop to it. Use the prop as the image.

Comment: You can give all the div's the same `class` name but a different `id`, and change only the `background-image` propriety for every `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide [props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) to the styled-component:

```
    export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px green solid;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-image: ${props => `url(${props.img})`};
    background-size:cover;
`
```

And than you will use it like that:

```
<StyledContainer img="https://www.ciakroncato.com/media/productpersonalize/productpersonalize/1541242051download.jpeg" />
```